# My jsconfig set up is not working with node in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

My config looks like the following:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "."
    },
  }
```

but I keep getting `Error: Cannot find module 'utils/calculateGetstation'`

Comment: Maybe `./utils/calculateGetstation`?

Comment: the utils folder is at the root of the project